# Problem with UITableView in XCode 12 and IOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios14, xcode12

I have a problem after upgrading to XCode 12 and IOS 14.

I normally set the background of a UITableView to .clear, for example:

```
  @IBOutlet weak var testTableView: UITableView!
```

and then in the viewDidLoad function:

```
testTableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```

This worked just fine for me. But since upgrading to XCode 12 and IOS 14 the background stays standard white until scrolling then it changes to .clear .

I didn't changed anything in my Code and with XCode 11 I didn't had this issue.

Does anyone has the same problem and figured out how to fix it?

thank you in advance

Comment: Did you try to set the background in Storyboard and see if this fixes the problem?

Comment: Yes but the problem remains - this seems like a bug in the compiler to me but im not sure. I didn‘t found a work around eighter. -

Comment: You sure the color you see is not the background color of the cell? It is easy to misinterpret those two :)

Comment: I am using a custom cell where the cell background is automatically set to .clear while initialization. Thats why this behavior is so weird because the cells which are present first have a white background but if you start scrolling and the TableView loads further cells the background of these „new“ cells is clear. If you then go back to the top cells which had the white background at the beginning these cells have also a clear background. At the beginning i thought this might be a bug in the recycling process so i tried to reload the TableView Elements but this also didn‘t help. 

Comment: I was suspecting this behaviour) Can you post your custom cell class? I think there is the problem.

Comment: I guess you’re right it must be the cell background. But its weird that this behavior just started with xCode 12 - Im not home right now but when i‘m back i can look at my class and if i didn’t find the issue i’ll post my class.

Comment: But again I’m very thankful for your help

Comment: No worries. I guess you assign a `.clear` background just inside the `prepareForReuse` method, but didn't put that inside `awakeFromNib` or maybe in a `setupCell` function or whatever else you called it where you actually populate the custom cell with the data. Good luck!

Comment: I‘ve fixed it! I called it at the right position in the Custom TableViewCell (in the override init() function) but instead of setting the background color to .clear i‘ve set it to .none this caused this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: Thank you all for your help.

I‘ve fixed it! It actually was a problem with the custom TableViewCell I don't know how I assumed that it was the general background of the TableView.(Thanks [@Starsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8314394/starsky) for the hint with custom Cell - i guess you all know after hours of searching for minor bugs you can't come up with the simplest things hahaha). In the `override init()` function of the custom cell I called `self.backgroundColor = .none` which caused the bug after setting it to `self.backgroundColor = .clear` everything works as planed.